# ADT did not show my phone that conect to pc with a usb cable

Tags: android

I am new in android programming I used **Genymotion** / **AVD** to run my app but I decide to use a **Sony Xperia LT26i** phone as a real device.

I connect it to pc and all the **USB** driver that it needs to get downloaded and my pc know my phone just there is a  **sony pc companion software** that it says it must be installed but it did not so I download it myself a setup it still asks to download it and it did not work . Anyway, my pc know my phone I can go to **"Xperia s portable media payer"** and it shows my phone file.
but ADT did not know my phone so I install **ADB-setup-1.4.3** that is provided for my phone a still ADT can not recognize it. what should I do?

Sorry for all the details I just say all of the things that I do so maybe it is better to get a good answer and **I also enable android developer and USB debugging on my phone**.

Comment: Did you try to configure the **Media Mode** in **Camera (PTP)** instead of **Media device (MTP)**?

Comment: hello thank u for answer .how ? i go to usb connection in my phone but there is not such a thing .

Comment: For Sony Mobile It's inside **Setting** -> **Xperia™** -> **USB Connectivity** and choose. Easy Method Just connect to Pc and Slide down notification bar there you can see Charging this device or something different.

Comment: i get there bt there is just install pc companion and no trusted hosts there . nothing else .

Comment: Please post your screenshot to understand properly and check if you have installed [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)

Comment: thank u . i use a root genius an root my phone and now ADT recognize it .

Answer (score 0):

Go to this site http://adbdriver.com/downloads/ and install the adbdriver run it with connecting your mobile..it will install the proper softwares